# Programatically bringing a Datagrid row into view in WPF, MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I would like to bring a row of my data grid into view programatically. I have a more than 100 rows. When I create a row(which I am doing by adding an item to a observable collection) I would like that new row to be selected and bring that into view. I was able to select the new row in my code but could not do the scrolling.  More over I want the first cell of the row to be in edit mode so that the user can input text. I am following MVVM pattern for the application and would like to keep zero code in my views. How Can I achieve this?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated....

**Update:**

This what I did in my XAML

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding AllPartClasses}" 
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPartClassViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"         
                     SelectionMode="Single" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

in my view model I did this

```
void AddNewPartClassExecute()
    {
        PartClass newPartClass = new PartClass();
        PartClassViewModel tempPartClass = new PartClassViewModel(newPartClass);
        tempPartClass.IsInValid = true;
        AllPartClasses.Add(tempPartClass);
        SelectedPartClassViewModel = tempPartClass;
        Global.DbContext.PartClasses.AddObject(newPartClass);

        //OnPropertyChanged("AllPartClasses");
    }
public PartClassViewModel SelectedPartClassViewModel 
    { 
        get
        {  
            return _selectedPartClassViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedPartClassViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPartClassViewModel");
        }
    }
```

It did not work for me.

Comment: Downvoted because "DataGrid" used in title is not RadGridView, which ruins search results.

Comment: Also, this should be downvoted for never having marked the correct answer, which is @KornMuffin's.

Answer (score 11):

For the regular WPF `DataGrid` you can use `ScrollIntoView`. In your view hookup the SelectionChanged event to the following in your view code-behind cs file.

```
private void OnSelectionChanged( object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e )
{
    Selector selector = sender as Selector;
    DataGrid dataGrid = selector as DataGrid;
    if ( dataGrid != null && selector.SelectedItem != null && dataGrid.SelectedIndex >= 0 )
    {
        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView( selector.SelectedItem );
    }
}
```

Comment: Or simpler: `if (sender is DataGrid dg)
{
    if (dg.SelectedItem != null)
        dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.SelectedItem);
}`

Answer (score 0):

When following MVVM pattern you should not do a UI-specific stuff like scrolling from a code.

Solution would be simple - just bind [DataGrid.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) to a property in ViewModel and when adding a new item in the items collection just update a property bound to `SelectedItem` so it would reference to just added item and data grid should select an appropriate row automatically.

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding UnderyingItemsCollection}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding RecentlyAddedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

Comment: Thank you much for looking. I did what you suggested. But no luck yet. I have added my code in the update section. please let me know if I am missing something. i did get the selected row but what shall I do get datagrid to scroll to bottom row...?

Comment: I've tried, but it is not scrolling to the `SelectedItem` row. I've tried to change `SelectedItem` from viewModel, however `DataGrid` is not scrolling to the row `SelectedItem`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. This is the proof that the MVVM pattern must not be always used strictly.

Comment: Downvoted because this answer is completely irrelevant.  He is already able to select from the VM, the question is about bringing it into view.